# Table valued function in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have used the functions in SQL Server for a long time. The functions can be used in the `FROM` clause and the `WHERE` clause can be specified.
In SQL Server the `WHERE` clause is used within the function itself. Unlike Oracle, the `WHERE` clause is applied after the function has produced the results.

The difference is important if the function without `WHERE` returns many results.
Furthermore, in SQL Server the indices inside the function are used if the WHERE is applied on the column with the index.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_test (
col1 varchar(50),
col2 varchar(50)
)

--INSERT TEST DATA
Declare @Id int
Set @Id = 1
While @Id <= 1000000
Begin 
   Insert Into table_test values ('col1' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)), 'col2' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)))
     Set @Id = @Id + 1
End


CREATE FUNCTION func_test() RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT * FROM table_test 
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixd_test ON table_test (col1) INCLUDE (col2)

SELECT * FROM func_test() WHERE col1 like 'col132%'
```

[image]

Is there a similar type of function in Oracle?

Comment: Not sure about the indexing part, but you can use Object Type Definitions in Oracle to get a similar outcome

Answer (score 0):

**Create table**

```
CREATE TABLE table_test (
    col1 varchar(50),
    col2 varchar(50)
)
```

**Once you fill the data in to `test_table` (using something like follows)**

```
Begin
for i in 1..1000000 loop
   Insert Into table_test values ('col1' || TO_CHAR(i), 'col2' || TO_CHAR(i));
end loop;
commit;
End;
/
```

**Something like follows may work. (Tested using oracle live sql)**

```
-- Create row definition
create OR REPLACE TYPE SOME_ROW_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
    COL1 varchar2(50),
    COL2 varchar2(50)
)
/
-- Create table definition
create type SOME_TABLE_TYPE as table of SOME_ROW_TYPE
/


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DoStuff RETURN SOME_TABLE_TYPE AS
-- Declarations
RET_TABLE SOME_TABLE_TYPE := SOME_TABLE_TYPE();
CURSOR DATA_FETCH IS
    SELECT
        COL1,
        COL2
    FROM TABLE_TEST;
BEGIN
FOR ITEM IN DATA_FETCH LOOP
RET_TABLE.extend;
RET_TABLE(RET_TABLE.LAST) := SOME_ROW_TYPE(
    ITEM.COL1,
    ITEM.COL2);
END LOOP;


RETURN RET_TABLE;
END;
/
```

**Creating index**

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_test(col1)
```

**fetch via**

```
select * from DoStuff() WHERE col1 like 'col132%'
```

Comment: It's better to make this function "pipelined": http://orasql.org/2017/12/13/collection-iterator-pickler-fetch-pipelined-vs-simple-table-functions/

Comment: I created an index on column col1 as in the example on Sql Server.
The function first returns all the data, then it is filtered.
I would like the function on Oracle to use the index inside the function like Sql Server.

Comment: When you looked at the sql server example, I believe the index is created outside the function scope. Happy to be wrong. Scope of the function declaration  starts at `CREATE FUNCTION` and ends at the proceeding `GO`. After that you have created an index on the actual table `table_test` itself

Comment: Alter the answer to pretty much match what you are doing in sql server. Have a look at using "pipelined" as mentioned by @SayanMalakshinov to improve the perf of this